# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre sobrescribir y sobrecargar un método?

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo herencia y me ha surgido esta duda, sé que por ejemplo para el método `toString()` se usa la sobrecarga, pero porqué no la sobreescritura?. Supuestamente la sobrecarga se da en métodos con diferentes parámetros pero `toString()` no tiene distintos parámetros, ¿es por eso que se escribe `@Override` para forzar la sobrecarga?. Si es así para que forzarla y no sobrescribirlo?. Para que me quede claro, dos constructores del mismo objeto estarían sobrecargados?. Ejemplo: `duda()` y `duda(boolean resuelta)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why

Comment: Si los parámetros son los mismos se sobremonta, cuando cambian se sobrecarga.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando utilizas `toString` estas sobrescribiendo no sobre cargando. Cuando agregas @Override estas anulando la funcionalidad por defecto que tiene un determinado método, es decir, estas sobrescribiendo el comportamiento.

La sobre carga de métodos ocurre cuando en una clase hay varios métodos con el mismo nombre pero diferentes parámetros. Esto no significa que al utilizar algunos de los método sobrecargados lo estas sobrescribiendo, si no que estas utilizando una de las variantes de los métodos que la clase tiene sobrecargados.

Por esa explicación te darás cuenta que el método `toString` no tiene sobre carga.

Un ejemplo de un método sobre cargado es por ejemplo en la misma clase String, con el método `valueOf()`

```
valueOf(boolean b)
valueOf(char c)
valueOf(char[] data)
```

En este caso ocurre una sobrecarga ya que el método tiene el mismo nombre pero se utilizan diferentes parámetros.

En cambio la sobrescritura ocurre cuando se hereda de una clase y se anula un método existente con la anotación @Override.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tienes una clase Vehiculo y una clase Coche que hereda de Vehiculo.

```
class Vehiculo {

    public void acelerar() {
        System.out.println("Vehiculo acelerando");
    }

}

class Coche extends Vehiculo {

    @Override   
    public void acelerar() {
        System.out.println("Coche acelerando");
    }
    
}
```

En este caso la clase `Coche` sobrescribe el método `acelerar()` de la clase `Vehiculo`.

---

En cuanto a tu pregunta sobre los dos constructores, te podrás dar cuenta que ocurre algo similar con la sobrecarga de métodos.

```
duda()
duda(boolean resuelta)
```

En este caso ocurre una sobrecara de constructores, ya que es el mismo principio de mismo nombre con diferentes parámetros. Esto se utiliza cuando se quiere tener la posibilidad de inicializar un objeto con diferentes datos.

Answer (score 2):

`@Override`

Se ocupa cuando quieres/necesitas ocupar tu propio método  y no el que viene heredado, como el `toString`, la documentación de Java dice que toda clase tiene a Object como una superclase y `toString` es un método de esta superclase.
Por eso siempre se debe ocupar el `@Override` para modificar el `toString` en la clase que lo quieras ocupar (el `toString` sin argumentos) .

El `toString` de la superclase retorna lo siguiente, el nombre de la clase y un hexadecimal que representa el hashCode.

`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

El método `toString` lo puedes sobrecargar si es que lo necesitas pero ya que es heredado de una superclase conviene hacerle un `@Override` para no "chocar" con el método de la superclase si es que existiera.

Acá la documentación oficial

[Java documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

Answer (score 0):

Al declarar un metodo `toString()` dentro de una clase (que sea similar en parámetros al `toString() contenido en la clase Object`) ya estas sobrescribiendo ese método, @Override no se usa para forzar nada, lo que hace es indicarle al compilador "el siguiente método es una sobreescritura de un método contenido en una clase superior en la jerarquía de clases". En ciertos IDE's no es estrictamente necesario que coloques @Override aunque hay otros IDE's en que sí. Usarlos siempre tiene 2 ventajas importantes:

1 - Extrae una advertencia del compilador si el método que tiene el annotation @Override en realidad no está sobrescribiendo nada.

2 - Mejora la legibilidad del código fuente.

Las anotaciones o annotations como @Override son metadatos, brindan información que puede resultar útil al compilador o a la Java Virtual Machine. Por el contrario al sobrecargar métodos no necesito colocar ninguna annotation, solo basta con que los métodos tengan diferentes parámetros:

```
public class Myclass {

  Integer myvar;
  
  Myclass(){}
  Myclass(Integer number){
    this.myvar = number;
  } // sobrecarga de contructores

  @Override // sobreescribiendo el metodo toString de la clase Object, el @Override no es estrictamente necesario pero previene algunos errores
  public String toString(){  
    return "" + this.myvar;
  }

  public String toString(String chain){ // aca no estoy sobreescribiendo toString, aqui estoy sobrecargando
    return chain + " " + this.myvar; 
  }

  // sobrecargando tambien, puedo usar la implementacion original toString() de la clase object usando la palabra super
  public String toString(Number number){ 
    return super.toString() + number;
  }
}
```